# Check if number is SMS/MMS capable before porting

Tags: twilio, sms

I would like to check if a set of US numbers are SMS capable - the customer would like to have both SMS and voice on the numbers and I'd like to know if this is possible before porting the numbers to Twilio.

I tried the [LookupAPI](https://www.twilio.com/docs/lookup/v2-api) but that does not seem to give me this information.

I then sent a SMS to the number to see if the SMS is delivered and I get a delivered status in the Twilio API, which in theory would mean that the number is SMS capable, but I'm not sure if this test is conclusive.

Is there any other way I could determine the number capabilities without owning the number?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All US numbers ported over to Twilio support both Voice and SMS.

Comment: Even toll free numbers?

Comment: Yes, Us/Canadian TF numbers.